# aapt always compresses resource files

Tags: android, ant, aapt

I have an Ant build script for my Android project. I’m using aapt to package various resource files. I want the resources files to be uncompressed. I ‘ve tried the ‘-0′ flag but the files still get compressed! But when I build through Eclipse, the resource files are uncompressed. Why doesn’t this flag work?

Here is my aapt target in Ant:

Packaging resources and assets...

Answer (score 3):

It is not the case that assets and raw resources are always uncompressed. [According to an Android developer](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/561e14c8078dc304), this was a mistake in the documentation, which has apparently now been removed.

In fact, whether a resource is compressed is controlled by its file type or by the -0 flag. See [Dealing with Asset Compression in Android Apps](http://ponystyle.com/blog/2010/03/26/dealing-with-asset-compression-in-android-apps/).

I know this doesn't answer your question and so should be posted as a comment, but I don't have comment posting rights yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered putting your resources in the `res/raw/` subdirectory instead?  Files placed in this directory are not compressed.  Alternatively, place your files in an `assets/` directory and read them using the `AssetManager` if you need the original hierarchy or file names in your application.

[Android documentation on resource types](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#ResourceTypes)

Comment: This is not correct. Files in res/raw can still get compressed.

Comment: Carsten is right, it really just depends on the file extension. For example the same exact file named video.mpg will not be compressed in the apk file, whereas if it were named video.m2v it would be.